# How to fix 'can not use mutating member on immutable value'?

Tags: swift

Getting the error:

> Error : cannot use mutating member on immutable value : 'fromArray' is a 'let' constant

In the following code:

```
func removing (item: Int, fromArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    for i in 0...fromArray.count-1 {
        if fromArray[i] == item {
            let index = i
            fromArray.remove(at: index) // <-- error is here
        }
    }
    return fromArray
}

var anarray : [Int] = [1, 2,3, 4 ,3]
var x = 3
removing(item: x, fromArray: anarray)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, you also have a problem of removing elements from the array and then going beyond its bounds. Try it like this:

```
func removeInPlace(item: Int, fromArray: inout [Int]) -> Void {

    for i in stride(from: fromArray.count - 1, to: 0, by: -1)
    {
        if fromArray[i] == item {
            fromArray.remove(at: i)
        }
    }

}

var anarray : [Int] = [1, 2,3, 4 ,3]

var x = 3

print(anarray)    // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 3]

removeInPlace(item: x, fromArray: &anarray)

print(anarray)    // prints [1, 2, 4]
```

You'll want additional error handling, but hope this helps get you on your way.

Comment: Up voted. I received a comment on exceeding bounds and, while a different question than the OP, I'm going to point him to your answer.

Answer (score 16):

Parameters in swift is constant by default, but if you want to mutate it in the function then it needs to be in place inout variable. You can achieve it by specifying the parameter as inout as follows

```
func removing (item: Int, fromArray : inout [Int]) -> [Int]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to modify a method parameter inside the method, you can declare it using the `inout` keyword (see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545)):

```
func removing(item: Int, fromArray: inout [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    ...
}
```

Without the `inout` keyword, all method parameters are constant values.

Answer (score 7):

The error you are seeing is due to trying to remove an array value from an array that is read-only. That is, `fromArray` is read-only and thus immutable. You have two options.

**Option #1: Make the input array read-write by adding an `inout` to it, and passing back nothing:**

```
func removing (item: Int, fromArray: inout [Int]) {

    for i in 0...fromArray.count-1 {
        if fromArray[i] == item {
            let index = i
            fromArray.remove(at: index) // Error : cannot use mutating member on immutable value : 'fromArray' is a 'let' constant
        }
    }
}
```

**Option #2: Use the function as is, but copying the array into a new one:**

```
func removing (item: Int, fromArray: inout [Int]) {

    var newArray = fromArray
    for i in 0...newArray.count-1 {
        if newArray[i] == item {
            let index = i
            newArray.remove(at: index) 
        }
    }
    return newArray
}
```

Unless indicated by `inout`, any parameter passed to a function in Swift is always read-only.

Comment: var anarray : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,3]
var x = 3
print ("\(removing(item: x, fromArray : &anarray))")

//when i add 'inout' and  i got   fatal error "index out of range "

Comment: That's a very different error. Let me check some things and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: option 3: just replace the whole thing with `anArray = anArray.filter { $0 != x }` :)

Comment: There are a few questions here on how best to correct this, but you have one here! You need to loop backwards through the array, and if you check the answer here by @DonMag you'll fix it.

Comment: @David_Berry, yes. I was answering the specifics in the question, not giving the *best* way to do it. (I'd do it that way also. No need for a separate function.)